# Azure Service Bus "ReceiveAsync"

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Is there a way, using the `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` package, to wait on your current thread to receive a message from a queue?

This may more be a problem with my understanding and a desire to use the technology in a way it is not intended to be used, but what I would like to do is combine the send and receive examples from [the following Microsoft example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues) so that you can send message(s) off to various queues, and be able to listen in and handle "replies" (just messages that you're listening to on a queue) and close the connection when you are done receiving messages.

Some pseudo-code here:

```
   // send message(s) that will be consumed by other processes / applications, and by doing so later on we will expect some messages back
   await SendMessagesAsync(numberOfMessages);

    var receivedMessages = 0;
    while (receivedMessages < numberOfMessages)
    {
        // there is no "ReceiveAsync" method, this is what I would be looking for
        Message message = await queueClient.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        receivedMessages++;

        // do something with the message here
   }

   await queueClient.CloseAsync();
```

Is this possible or am I "doing it wrong"?

Comment: ReceiveAsync mehtod is available in https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/4.1.9 but not in https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/. So here either you can use the first package, or you can write a logic to make `Recieve` as blocking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the new library `ReceiveAsync` method is available on `MessageReceiver` class:

```
var messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver(SBConnString, QueueName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
Message message = await messageReceiver.ReceiveAsync();
```

See a full example at [Get started sending and receiving messages from Service Bus queues using MessageSender and MessageReceiver](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet/GettingStarted/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/SendReceiveUsingMessageSenderReceiver).

Comment: which one is recommended foe azure functions ?  your ans or below `ReceiveOrProcessMessagesAsync` ans? please guide?

Comment: Azure Functions Service Bus trigger handles the receival of messages for you, so you shouldn't need any of these. Or aren't you using the trigger?

Answer (score 1):

In `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` library, there is no such a thing called`ReceiveAsync`. In  this, you can process or receive the message by using `RegisterOnMessageHandlerAndReceiveMessages()`. With this you can receive the message with an event. With this `RegisterOnMessageHandlerAndReceiveMessages()` like `queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ReceiveOrProcessMessagesAsync, messageHandlerOptions);` and you have to seprately create this event for receiveMessages, in our case it is `ReceiveOrProcessMessagesAsync`

```
static async Task ReceiveOrProcessMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
    {
        // Process the message
        Console.WriteLine($"Received message: SequenceNumber:{message.SystemProperties.SequenceNumber} Body:{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}");

        // Complete the message so that it is not received again.
        // This can be done only if the queueClient is created in ReceiveMode.PeekLock mode (which is default).
        await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);

        // Note: Use the cancellationToken passed as necessary to determine if the queueClient has already been closed.
        // If queueClient has already been Closed, you may chose to not call CompleteAsync() or AbandonAsync() etc. calls 
       // to avoid unnecessary exceptions.
    }
```

and you refer the below link for know about `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues

Comment: which one is recommended foe azure functions ? your ans or below ReceiveOrProcessMessagesAsync ans? please guide?

Comment: do you want to get the invocation logs of Azure functions?

Comment: For Azure Functions,  install `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions`. This package contains all the necessary things to perform on Azure Functions